# Two way data binding using jQuery dataTable and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which gets it's data using jQueryDataTable.

```
$('#myTableName').DataTable(
        {
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/API/Loaddata",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "IsSelected",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (type === 'display') {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" class="editor-active">';
                        }
                        return data;
                    },
                    "className": "dt-body-center"
                   // "autoWidth": true
                },
                { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true }
            ],
            "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
                // Set the checked state of the checkbox in the table
                $('input.editor-active', row).prop('checked', data.active == 1);
            }
        }
    );
```

Now to get data I have following code,

```
  private static IEnumerable<CircState> rCirc;
  [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LoadData()
        {
            rCirc= _repo.GetAll().OrderBy(circ => circ.ID).Select(x => new CState { IsSelected = true, Name = x.Name });

            return Json(new { data = circuits }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This works fine an I get following JSON, which is bound to my view:

```
{
    "data":
    [
    {"IsSelected":true,"Name":"SMyDataPoint__01"},
    {"IsSelected":true,"Name":"SMyDataPoint__04"},
    {"IsSelected":true,"Name":"SMyDataPoint__07"},
    {"IsSelected":true,"Name":"SMyDataPoint__08"},
    {"IsSelected":true,"Name":"SMyDataPoint__09"},
    {"IsSelected":true,"Name":"SMyDataPoint__10"},
    {"IsSelected":true,"Name":"SMyDataPoint__11"}
    ]
}
```

This is my UI code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cirs, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <table id="filtersTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Select</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now when I am tick/untick an item and click on submit button, How can I get the unslected items.

What I need is two-way binding between View and Model , so When I call following code , I should get all the items based on there state(true/false).

```
 $('#btnRunReport').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Circuits/SelectedCircs/",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    console.log('Error');
                }
            });


        });



[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult SelectedCirs()
        {
         //rCirc is the global variable decalred on top (In First API)
            var selectedCircs = rCirc.Where(x => x.IsSelected == false);
            return Json(selectedCircuits);
        }
```

Comment: Since the only other property in the json data is `Name`, are you wanting to post back just the values of the selected names?

Comment: I have ID  also associated with the class but no shown just to keep the code clean.

Comment: Have you want to get all selected rows with checkbox checked and pass values into action method? This fiddle may show you something until submit request: https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abhbs4x8/.

Comment: Is there a column for the `ID` property in the table (if so, you should update the json data and `DataTable` code - you will need javascript/jquery to build an array to pass back to the controller based on if the checkbox is checked)? Its also a bit unclear what the method you posting to is going to do